# How do I automatically run an application that requires administrator privilege in Windows 8

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-8, autorun, elevated-privileges

I have an application that I need to automatically run on windows 8 WITH elevated privilege.
I have embedded the manifest which contains the requireAdministrator attribute of the requestedExecutionLevel and this works fine when run from a mouse click, however I need the application to automatically run.

This works fine on vista and windows 7 but not on windows 8 ... it simply just doesn't run. How do I get it to execute and prompt the user for permission?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any Windows 8 installation available to test this on, but I encountered a similar problem when requiring admin privileges in a Click Once deployment (where you are not allowed to use the manifest).

Solved it by having the application do a check at startup if it is running as admin or not, if it's not running as admin it restarts itself as admin.

Here is the code (slightly modified) that I use:

```
public static bool IsRunningAsAdministrator()
{
    var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);

    return wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}

public static void StartAsAdmin(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsRunningAsAdministrator())
        return;

    // It is not possible to launch a ClickOnce app as administrator directly, so instead we launch the app as administrator in a new process.
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);

    // The following properties run the new process as administrator
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";

    // Start the new process
    Process.Start(processInfo);

    // Shut down the current process
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

**Update after testing on a lot of machines:** One problem I bumped into with this solution is that anti-virus software often sees this as suspicious behaviour and blocks the startup.

I ended up changing the installer + auto updating from Click Once to [WiX Toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) + [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/nappupdate) and run with `requestedExecutionLevel="requireAdministrator"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I need the application to automatically run.

I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically run" but I assume that you want your application to run when the user logs in, at a certain time or when some other trigger condition is met. You can use Task Scheduler to make this happen. If the user has administrative privileges you can request that Task Scheduler runs the application "with highest" privileges. To do that you have to check "Run with highest privileges" in the properties for the task:

[image: Task properties]

Note that no UAC prompt is shown to the user when Task Scheduler executes that task even though it executes with administrative privileges.